# set margin and padding as 0 for top and bottom in html emails

Tags: html, css, email

I have a table for an html email as

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20">
<tr>
 <td>Content 1</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
 <td>content 2</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Here I want to retain the cellpadding ="20" on the left and right part of the cells , but I do not want to have any spacing / padding between the top and bottom part of the cells.

I can use `<td style="margin:0 20; padding:0 20"` to achieve this. However many of the older email clients will not pick up this css. How can this be achieved so that it is recognized in all email clients?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the given URL

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Margins and paddings are accepted by many mail clients.